# Get-ExecutionPolicy y Get-ExecutionPolicy no funciona

Tags: cmd, powershell

Estoy intentando utilizar el comando Get-ExecutionPolicy y Set-ExecutionPolicy en el cmd para poder habilitar la ejecución de scripts, pero me sale un mensaje que dice: "no se reconoce como comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable".
Siguiendo la guía de algunos sitios de internet he intentado agregar las siguientes variables de entorno al sistema:
%SystemRoot%\system32
%SystemRoot%
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
Pero no ha funcionado.
Agradecería mucho la ayuda de alguien a quien le haya pasado lo mismo y haya podido encontrar una solución.
Las características de mi sistema operativos son:
Windows 10 Pro
versión: 20H2
Compilación del sistema operativo: 19042.804

Comment: Estás ejecutando los comandos en PowerShell o en la consola de Windows de toda la vida (`cmd`)?

Comment: Con la consola cmd

Comment: Dichos *cmdlets* pertenecen al módulo de PowerShell [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Security`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/?view=powershell-7.1), por lo que lo correcto sería ejecutarlos **PowerShell**, como se indica en los ejemplos y no en un cmd. No creo necesario crear una respuesta, pues con la información proporcionada debería ser más que suficiente. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-ExecutionPolicy es un cmdlet de Powershell y tiene que ejecutarse en la consola de Powershell.  También es necesario que tengas el privilegio de administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Antes tienes que ejecutar este comando

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

suerte!

Comment: Explica brevemente qué hace el comando que mencionas: lee [answer]. Además, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].